# type object 'Event' has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I am getting the following error:

`AttributeError at /admin2/event/edit/1/
type object 'Event' has no attribute '_default_manager'`

from the newly added code:

(views.py)

```
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class EditEvent(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'admin2/events/edit-event.html'
    form_class = AddEventForm
    model = Event
    slug_url_kwarg = "events_id"
    slug_field = 'id'
    success_url = '/admin2/event/'
```

(urls.py)

```
url(r'^admin2/event/edit/(?:(?P<events_id>.+)/)?$', login_required(EditEvent.as_view()), name='edit-event-view'),
```

(models.py)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(help_text='Name of the event', max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(help_text='Location of the event', max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
```

(forms.py)

```
class AddEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('title', 'location', 'date')
```

Full traceback here:

http://dpaste.com/002BGGT

I am using Django 1.11 (outdated but I am unable to update)

Comment: This is the entire `Event` model? No extra managers, `Meta` options, etc.?

Comment: You might have imported the wrong `Event` class in `forms.py`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thats the entire model

Comment: @Selcuk only 1 `Event` model class to import to `forms.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

I renamed my view to EditIndiView and renamed my model to IndiView, however, I did not have any conflicting names...regardless, the renaming of the model and view solved the error.